# Background color depending on external function value on the same plot

Tags: list-manipulation, background

I would like to plot a two dimensional list (ListPLot [{x, y[x]}]) where the background color is changing with x value according to the value assumend by an external function f[x]. Thank you.
Sorry, I have to be more precise. This is what I mean fo the function Plot

```
f[x_] := 6 E^-x Sin[2*Pi*x^2];
g[x_] := Sin[2*x*10];
Plot[{f[x], ConditionalExpression[0, g[x] < 0]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, None}, 
Filling -> {2 -> {Bottom, Red}, 2 -> {Top, Red}}]
```

I would like to be the same working with list and ListLinePLot.

Comment: Can you make the question more specific and concrete by assigning functions to `y` and `f`?

Comment: Are you really talking about background color (e.g. something like `ContourPlot`), or do you want to change the color of the individual points according to your function `f[x]`?

Comment: I think the OP wants a `DensityPlot` in the background with a `ListLinePlot` in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

- `Plot`.

```
f[x_] := 6 E^-x Sin[2*Pi*x^2];
g[x_] := Sin[2*x*10];
Plot[{f[x], f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][g@x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, Filling -> {{1 -> Bottom}, {2 -> Top}},
  Epilog -> 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], White}][[1]]]
```

[image]

- `ListPlot`+ `Joined -> True`

```
f[x_] := 6 E^-x Sin[2*Pi*x^2];
g[x_] := Sin[2*x*10];
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2, .1}];
ListPlot[{data, data}, Joined -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][g@x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, Filling -> {{1 -> Bottom}, {2 -> Top}},
  Epilog -> ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> White, Joined -> True][[1]]]
```

[image]

- `ListPlot`+ `Joined -> False`

[image]

Comment: No, I would like to work with the list, so ListPlot, not PLot.

Comment: This solution is quite good but seems rather contrived; thank you. Is there another solution? More direct. Besides, a red stripe is sufficient! Directly on the background